# Transporting values in arrays within scopes in Swing - java

Tags: java, arrays, swing, combobox, jbutton

my goal is to be able to draw graphs and then save its values if required.
[image: ComboBox and Button]

In the image above, I choose from the comboBox a specific type of graph to draw, except for Clear, which just clears the graph that is shown. This is already working correctly. 
I have an arrayList of UserPattern(I created) objects that contains a string, a double and a double array.

I want to store the values from the graph in some variable (i'm currently using a double array) to use it later on.
With the double array I've had problems with the passing of values, since when I press "Save Pattern" it keeps the latest values of the graph (the last graph shown) and inputs it on every element of the UserPattern List that I have previously saved. So, even if I save multiple patterns, they all keep the value of the last save.

This is the code I use to store the values in the ArrayList:

```
private void readAndInsertPatternValues(List<UserPattern> patternLi, double[] graphValue) {



    UserPattern tempUserPattern = new UserPattern(typePattern);
    //extra code

        tempUserPattern.setMonthlyConsump(consTemp);
        tempUserPattern.setNameID(patternName);
        tempUserPattern.setPatternValues(graphValue);
        patternLi.add(tempUserPattern);
        System.out.println("Inserted: ");
        System.out.println(tempUserPattern);

    }
}
```

I call this method within a mouse event on the button "Save Pattern":

```
    JButton btnSaveUserPattern = new JButton("Save Pattern");
    btnSaveUserPattern.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            if(!((comboBoxPattern.getSelectedItem()).equals(UserPattern.PatternType.CLEAR)))
                readAndInsertPatternValues(patternList, patternValue);

            for(UserPattern upTemp : patternList) {
                System.out.println("Inside the Pattern List:");
                System.out.println(upTemp.toString());
            }
        }
    });
    btnSaveUserPattern.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    btnSaveUserPattern.setEnabled(false);
```

Also, I get the values that create the graph in the event from selecting an option of the combobox:

```
 comboBoxPattern = new JComboBox<UserPattern.PatternType>();
    comboBoxPattern.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    comboBoxPattern.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        //this method creates the graphs, so I send the array "patternValue" to "get" the values.
            printPatternGraph(comboBoxPattern, chartPanel, "User Pattern for Energy Consumption", "Hours", "Energy Consumption(Wh)", true, patternValue);

            btnSaveUserPattern.setEnabled(true);

        }
    });
```

I initialized the patternValue array as a local variable in the method that calls and uses the above mentioned methods as such:

```
double[] patternValue = new double[1440];
```

With all this, happened the problem in transporting values. At the "insertion time", the console showed the correct values, however, when I clicked on the "Save Pattern" button, which shows all the objects in the UserPattern list, the graph values from the previously saved graphs were equal to the one I saved last. (The last one I saved corrupted all the others).

I tried to change the way of passing values and changed the method "printPatternGraph" to return a double[] array, and made like this:

```
  patternValue=printPatternGraph(comboBoxPattern, chartPanel, "User Pattern for Energy Consumption", "Hours", "Energy Consumption(Wh)", true);
```

This, however, brought me the error,

```
Local variable patternValue defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final.
```

Therefore, I tried making "patternValue" a global variable . This actually solved the problem, but I don't think that this is the best solution (I've read multiple times that global variables are "bad coding".

This way, which way do you think I should implement this?

Thanks for your attention and sorry for the long post,

nhekas

Comment: If all this program does is make these graphs, I don't see why your graph data shouldn't be a global variable.  Variables should be defined in the smallest scope that encompasses their use.  If the entire program uses your graph data, a global variable isn't bad just because your textbook says so.

Comment: No, this is one part of my program. My program is a UI Interface that users can insert these "patterns" (based on the graphs), and other two types of objects stored on lists like the Patterns. 

Then, I use these 3 to create simulations and manipulate each other. And since none of the others required global variables, I'd like to keep it that way (although the other objects don't have a double array as a component).

Comment: please whats reason to define a `DefaultComboBoxModel` twice `comboBoxPattern = new JComboBox<UserPattern.PatternType>();` and `comboBoxPattern.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(UserPattern.PatternType.values()));`, are you sure (description in your question to talks about) that `ItemListener` added to `JComboBox` isn't better than `ActionListener`

Comment: "(I've read multiple times that global variables are "bad coding"": if you are going by rumor and imposing talk you will not get my answer - plus you are asking us to find a variabe in the hay stack: nobody will do that

Comment: @mKorbel, the definition was a typo, my error, I already fixed it. I have not tried     ItemListener just yet, but I will and will get back to you. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @gpasch Hello, I'm not saying by rumour, every teacher that taught me to use Java has told me: "avoid global variables until it is impossible not to".
I'm not sure that what I'm achieveing is impossible, that is why I posted this question.
I wanted to know why using a double array[] initiated locally and passing it through other method calls would "corrupt" the values when inserted in an ArrayList. Sorry if I mislead, but that is my problem.

Comment: What is the value of the "typePattern" argument being passed to the UserPattern constructor?

Comment: @ChadNC it is the selection of the ComboBox. Can be CLEAR, SIN, WINTER_BASED or SUMMER_BASED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

I understood what was wrong! Sorry to bother you guys. 
My problem, was, that when I added the double array to the ArrayList, I did it like this:

```
patternLi.add(graphValues);
```

This, instead of storing the values inside the graphValue array, was storing the reference to it. Therefore, when I wanted to create a different graph, the reference to the graph was the same, but changed the values.

I had to do the following:

```
new double[] arrayTemp= new double[1440];
for ( int i=0; i<1440;i++) {
    arrayTemp[i]=graphValues[i];
}
patternLi.add(arrayTemp);
```

This way, it worked! Because, since arrayTemp is local, is created everytime I call the method and passes the correct values.
Thanks for all your input guys !

nhekas